# /post request containing data using request.payload (hapi.js)

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I'm trying to do a /post request to my server that gives data (saves to db (knex)) using Hapi.js.

Along with the post request, i'm trying to use 2 functions that will turn a random number into a hex string and set it to the hexString key in my data object.

***routes.js***

```
module.exports.postData = {
  method: 'POST',
  path: '/',
  handler: (request, reply) => {
    const post = request.payload
    const data = {
      id: uuid.v4(),
      timeOut: null,
      uri: post.uri,
      payload: post.payload,
      hexString: undefined
    }
    store.link.createRandomInt()
      .then((randomNum) => {
        store.link.createHexString(randomNum)
          .then((hex) => {
            data.hexString = hex
            reply(store.link.createLink(data)).code(201)
          })
      })
   }
}
```

***functions.js***

```
module.exports.createRandomInt = function () {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000000))
    resolve(randomNumber)
  })
}

module.exports.createHexString = function (int) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var hexString = int.toString(32)
    resolve(hexString)
  })
}
```

***dbFunctions.js***

```
module.exports = {
  createLink: function (link) {
    return db('links').insert(link)
      .then((id) => {
        return {
          id: uuid.v4(),
          timeOut: null,
          uri: link.uri,
          payload: link.payload,
          hexString: link.hexString
        }
      })
   }
}
```

***Post Curl Command:***

```
curl http://localhost:8000/ -d "uri: 'this is the uri' payload: { jsonObj: 'enter payload info here'}"
```

***What Post Curl Command Returns:***

```
{"id":"87c467dd-3703-4f9f-a1ac-78551dc33109","timeOut":null}
```

***When I console.log() the returned data object:***

```
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
```

Thanks for any input~

Comment: The db createlink promise does not appear to be resolving properly, can we see complete code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out why it wasn't posting data.
My curl command was wrong.

Here would be a correct curl command:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"uri": "this uri", "payload": "enter payload info here"}' http://localhost:8000/
```

***routes.js***

```
handler: (request, reply) => {
    const post = request.payload
    const key = store.util.createRandomInt()
    const data = {
      id: uuid.v4(),
      timeOut: null,
      uri: post.uri,
      payload: post.payload,
      key: key,
      hexString: store.util.convertToHexString(key)
    }
    const result = store.sqlStore.createLink(data)
    reply(result).code(201)
}
```